# BQ Aquaris E4.5 sound not working in web applications and mediaplayer

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, phone

I've recently purchased the BQ Aquaris E4.5 with Ubuntu touch and I'am quite satisfied for this first release. However I encountered some issues concerning the sound on the device.

When I go to sound settings the sound is fully up. I can select ringtones and it plays back the selected ringtone through the speaker, and also through the jack plug seems to work fine. Playing the pre installed game Pathwind also gives me sound.

However, sound from webpages such as Youtube and the mediaplayer are not playing back any sound. Somebody some idea's how to solve this issue? Or maybe some commands to run some diagnostics? It might be a bug, but it might be just a config issue. I'm sure it's not a hardware problem since it plays back in ringtones and in the supplied game.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned having played Pathwind; did you by any chance mute the sound in Pathwind? There's a known bug whereby muting the sound in Pathwind mutes the sound for the rest of the system as well -- this can be fixed by just relaunching Pathwind and unmuting the sound.

Comment: Wow, that was a quick response! And yes.. indeed I have muted the sound in Pathwind. Unmuting it did not solve the issue, however unmuting it and rebooting the phone seems to give me full sound on all applications. Thank you very much, this solved my problem.